# Firefox - Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available. Ubuntu 20.04 New Install

Tags: firefox, video, 20.04

Firefox will periodically not play videos giving me this error:

---

> Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats >
>   available.Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about >
>   HTML5 video.

---

Chromium plays the video fine.

I get the error using a fresh install Ubuntu 20.04 with third party software option checked on install.

Issue started in Ubuntu 19.10 when I switched over from Comcast to Sonic fiber had error with other versions of Firefox.

My network has Snort configured on a Pfsense router but the error still occurs when I disable Snort and clear all blocked URLs.

What can I check?

Answer (score 8):

I've run into the same problem and it looks like installing ubuntu-restricted-extras did the trick:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This solved my problem with Firefox + Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I also went through the same issue. After some digging I read on Netflix website that the Firefox should be "verified" one. So I manually installed the Firefox issued by "Mozilla". And everything is working fine now.

Comment: Can you please link the website page where you read the same? It will help the seekers to verify the information and check for more if they have further queries.